# I made animation in android and got this error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:Integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

after this code i got this error

> @android:Integer/config_mediumAnimTime' is incompatible with attribute duration (attr) integer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is due to the fact that you put the letter P after 100%

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:Integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" //<<--here
    android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

or specify just a milliseconds in "duration"

Comment: No brother its not the problem still got the same error the error IDE show me is in this line `android:duration="@android:Integer/config_mediumAnimTime"`

Comment: @SulemanBajwa Why don't you specify the duration of the animation in Miliseconds instead of text

Comment: i dont know the value

Comment: Just hold ctrl and click LMB on the name "config_mediumAnimTime" and you will see what it is in general

Comment: look this image https://imgur.com/a/1dfutpE

Comment: 400  Miliseconds